# getting the strength(graph) when calculating the degree(graph) in R

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I am getting the strength(graph) instead of the degree when calculating the degree(graph) in an undirected weighted network where I have uploaded the data in the form of an edge list. Can somebody help me know why?

Comment: can you share example data?

Comment: ... and some code please

Comment: I am afraid I am not authorised to share the data. But some of the rows representing the edges in the edge list do have duplicates.

Comment: you dont need to share your actual data. Create some that reproduces the behaviour you are seeing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example gives some pointers on how to do this.